# 302 error when filtering routes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, filtering, laravel-middleware

I'm just starting learning Laravel filtering routes. I have this code, it should redirect to a URL, but I get a 302 error:

Routes `web.php`

```
Route::get('/birthday', function() {
    return view('birthday');
});
```

View `birthday.php`

```
<body>
    <h1> Hello world! </h1>
    <p> Hello! </p>
</body>
```

Middleware `birthday.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    if (1) {
        return redirect('/birthday');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

`Kernel.php` in middleware property

```
...
\App\Http\Middleware\birthday::class,
...
```

Comment: I don't see you using the Middleware `birthday.php` anywhere. What route are you expecting to redirect to `/birthday`?

Comment: @TimLewis birthday is the name of my middleware too

Comment: I know that, but **where are you using it**? I don't see `["middleware" => "birthday"]` anywhere, and you don't provide enough of your `Kernel.php` for me to determine if it's in a middleware group or anything.

Comment: `protected $middleware = [ `     
        `\App\Http\Middleware\birthday::class,`
       
  ];`

Comment: @TimLewis in which part I need to put this? `["middleware" => "birthday"]`

Comment: Ok, so it's being included globally. Good to know. `["middleware" => "birthday"]` is for including it as a one-off on a specific Route or RouteGroup in `web.php`; not applicable to this. I don't think 302 is an error btw; what route are you accessing when you get that? *"The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection."*

Comment: localhost/blog/public and it redirect me to localhost/blog/public/my/birthday and it show me that error

Comment: When I use the "Inspect Element" in Firefox it show me that error

Comment: What error? And `return redirect('birthday');` wouldn't redirect to `/my/birthday`, rather `/birthday`, which will put you in a loop... If every request redirects to `/birthday`, including `/birthday`, that's an infinite loop...

Comment: Sorry I've fixed the code,take a look now. I know that is the problem, but I cant see where

Comment: `if (1) { return redirect('/birthday'); }` That will **always** redirect you to `mysite/birthday`, even if you're already on `mysite/birthday`. You've got an infinite loop, you need to change your `if()` condition to something that can be false.

Comment: Thank you very much @TimLewis. I will check that and let you know.

Comment: @TimLewis How I did not notice that!!! I was testing an example and I have reviewed all the code trying to find the wrong fragment and I just look in everywhere but not that one. unbelievable!! The most of the time the mistake are very simple and we are looking for big things. Thank you so much for your time!